# ¿Cómo borrar un elemento de un JSON con Python?

Tags: python-3.x, json

Tengo un archivo JSON el cual deseo modificar, eliminando algunas secciones del JSON.
En el siguiente segmento deseo eliminar los campos donde el sku = "YS-TG100" y "vSBC One"

```
[
   {
      "sku": "YS-TA800",
      "manufacturer_sku": "TA800",
      "manufacturer": "Yeastar",
      "title": "NEOGATE TA800 8FXS GATEWAY",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "177.8",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "3"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "1"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "sku": "YS-TG100",
      "manufacturer_sku": "TG100",
      "manufacturer": "Yeastar",
      "title": "NEOGATE TG100 1GSM PORT",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "0",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "0"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "2"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "sku": "YS-TG100-UMTS",
      "manufacturer_sku": "TG100-UMTS",
      "manufacturer": "Yeastar",
      "title": "NEOGATE TG100-UMTS",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "231",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "3"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "0"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "sku": "vSBC One",
      "manufacturer_sku": "None",
      "manufacturer": "None",
      "title": "Pago Mensual de Soporte para vSBC One Blunde Manage",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "0",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "900"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "10"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Quedando como resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
[
   {
      "sku": "YS-TA800",
      "manufacturer_sku": "TA800",
      "manufacturer": "Yeastar",
      "title": "NEOGATE TA800 8FXS GATEWAY",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "177.8",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "3"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "1"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "sku": "YS-TG100-UMTS",
      "manufacturer_sku": "TG100-UMTS",
      "manufacturer": "Yeastar",
      "title": "NEOGATE TG100-UMTS",
      "currency": "USD",
      "price": "231",
      "warehouses": {
         "1": {
            "stock": "3"
         },
         "2": {
            "stock": "0"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Lo intenté de la siguiente manera, pero solo funciona con el último elemento del JSON:

```
import json
firstData  = json.load(open("payload.json"))
                                              
for row in range(len(firstData)):
    if firstData[row]["sku"] == "vSBC One":
        firstData.pop(row)
                            
open("payload1.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(firstData, indent=4)
)
```

Si pongo en el if "YS-TG100" me maarca un error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Nordata\Desktop\Conexion\borrado.py", line 5, in <module>
    if firstData[row]["sku"] == "YS-TG100":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Al JSON se le han de añadir mas datos y quisiera poder borrar cualquier sección sin depender de la posición en la que se encuentra el elemento, ya que el JSON pudiera crecer y la posición no serviría.
He probado distintos métodos de varios foros pero no he conseguido una forma de hacer.
¿Podrían apoyarme?

Comment: Puedes usar algo así  `firstData = [x for x in firstData if x["sku"] !=  "vSBC One"]`

Comment: Que tal Jaime, en efecto, esa estructura funcionó y pude eliminar cualquier sección del objeto.
Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una simple comprensión de lista lo puedes hacer. Donde recorremos la lista y creamos una nueva lista cuyos diccionarios en la posción `sku` no sea `YS-TG100` ni `vSBC One`

```py
firstData = [x for x in firstData if not x["sku"] in ["YS-TG100","vSBC One"]]

json.dumps(firstData)
```

Todo es mágia de la condición `if not x["sku"] in ["YS-TG100","vSBC One"]` donde decimos que el `sku` **no** esté en la lista `["YS-TG100","vSBC One"]` (oséa que no sea ninguna de esas 2 opciones).

Si no te resulta cómoda la comprensión de lista puedes usar un ciclo `for` convencional

```py
data_final = []

for x in firstData:
    if not x["sku"] in ["YS-TG100","vSBC One"]:
        data_final.append(x)

json.dumps(data_final)
```